# A proof for $x^a$ is concave where $a \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I was trying to prove $x^a$ where $a\in(0,1)$ is a concave function for $x\geq0$. I need to show that $f((1-t)x+ty)\geq(1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$.

I put the LHS as $[(1-t)x+ty]^a$ and RHS as $(1-t)x^a+ty^a$. I tried to take $y^{1/a}$ on both sides, but I do not know how to expand a non-integer power since binomial theorem only works on positive integer powers.

Could someone give me a hint to proceed? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of Calculus?

Comment: @jjagmath I am not sure what you are referring to as basics of calculus?

Comment: There is a relation between the second derivative and concavity of a given function. It's very likely that in your calculus class, you were given a test to show that a function is concave using the second derivative. This is likely what jjagmath is referring to. If you don't have this result, then I guess the point of the exercise is to prove it.

Comment: Never heard of limits, continuity, derivatives?

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed This is a part of my proof to show that $d(x,y)^a$ is a metric given $d(x,y)$ is a metric. I want to use $x^a$ to show triangle inequality if I can prove $(x+y)^a\leq x^a+y^a$. Basically, I was trying to show that $x^a$ is concave so that it is subadditive, which will help me to prove triangle inequality. I am unsure if I can just use the second derivative test to say it is concave or I must use the definition to prove it and then proceed to subadditivity.

Comment: @jjagmath If you are referring to use second derivative test to show $x^a$ is concave, then I am aware of that. But like I mentioned in the reply, I am not sure if I can just use second derivative test in my proof or I must prove it from the definition.

Comment: For the triangle inequality it suffices to show that $(1+x)^a\le x^a+1$ for $x\ge 0.$ Analyze the function $f(x)=1+x^a-(1+x)^a.$ Applying the first derivative prove that $f$ is increasing, therefore $f(x)\ge f(0)=0.$ By the way not every concave function is subadditive

Comment: If you've learned the second derivative test, you can probably use it. Also, not every concave function is subadditive, but since $0^a = 0 \geq 0$, $x^a$ is subadditive. Ryszard is right though, even without the preceding facts, you can use elementary calculus to get the result.